# Adding hyperlink in mysql fetched data

Tags: php, html, mysql

In this script i am trying to generate results in such a way that we can make data in hyperlink form.

```
echo '<td> <a href="www.'.$arr['website'] .'"></a></td>';
```

if i type the above query it does not display any result. Could anyone guide me where did i go wrong?

Comment: You don't have anything in the link, the `<a>` tag is empty.

Comment: the source will be populated but  the browser has nothing to display

Comment: @Dan It worked, Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<td> <a href="www.'.$arr['website'] .'">'.$arr['website'].'</a></td>';
```

Should do it. Or, if it's some other aspect of the array, use that (e.g., $arr['sitename']).

Comment: URLs need to be prefixed with a protocol, otherwise they're treated as relative and you'll end up with `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876250/adding-hyperlink-in-mysql-fetched-datawww.yourwebsite.com`

Answer (score 1):

It looks good except you don't have anything in your `<a>` tag.  Try adding some text in there like this:

```
echo '<td> <a href="www.'.$arr['website'] .'">Link Text</a></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, there's no problem with the anchor tag not having anything between its opening and closing tags, but only when its `display` attribute is set to `block` (even `inline-block`) and as long as you specify a `width` and a `height`, as the following example demonstrates:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank"></a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

You can play with [its fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/RJ6ga/1/).